Do flickr authors license their photos to be shared with the embed script for free as part of the TOS?
Flickr provides an "embed" feature that allows users to share photos on external websites by embedding them while linking back to Flickr. I’m wondering if this automatically grants a free-use license to the photo, even for commercial use, just by virtue of the embed script being available. Specifically:

Does Flickr's TOS state that authors are licensing their photos for free when embedding is enabled?
Does using the embed feature mean the author relinquishes control over how the photo is used on external sites, or do they retain the right to restrict certain uses, such as for commercial purposes?
The feature can easily mislead a user into thinking that the particular use is allowed because of the backlink to the photo and given that the platform has still control to display all necessary copyright notices in the target website.

I'm trying to understand the legal implications for both authors and those who embed the content, especially in terms of commercial vs. non-commercial use.
Any clarification on how Flickr's TOS addresses these permissions would be helpful.
If this is not part of the TOS, then isn't the platform liable for damages caused by this feature? (Both to users and authors)
What about other platforms?
Reference: https://www.flickr.com/help/terms

I’m voting to close this question because Flickr's TOS are not the law.

@bdb484 How to interpret a contract is a legal issue.

Company A freely licenses its software in exchange for an agreement not to make any advertisements that feature "dangerous dogs" for the next 3 years. Company B is developing an advertising campaign featuring Clifford, but then it used A's software. Does B retain the right to use A's software? How to interpret the contract is a legal issue, but "Is Clifford a dangerous dog?" is not a legal question.

Yes, this activity is covered by the Terms of Use (emphasis mine):


Account Security

User Content that you post, upload or otherwise make available via the Services may be accessed, used and downloaded by other users of the Services. You understand and acknowledge that any User Content contained in public areas of the Services, including any user galleries or other portions of the Services, is accessible to the public and could be accessed, downloaded, indexed, archived, linked to and republished by others including, without limitation, appearing on other websites and in search engine results. Flickr provides privacy options and settings for your content available in the Privacy & Permissions section of your applicable user account (the “Account Settings”).

In other words, embedding scripts are a permissible part of "the Services" to which you've licensed your content by uploading it.
Anyone else wishing to use your content, by embedding or otherwise, is subject to the same Terms of Use, including a general prohibition against:

any resale, commercial use, commercial exploitation, distribution, public performance or public display of the Services or the Flickr Materials;
with the exception of User Content made available by users for download, the downloading of any portion of the Flickr Materials or any information contained therein; or
any use of the Services or the Flickr Materials other than for their intended purposes.

As long as the third party's use abides by those restrictions, the uploader may not further restrict it.

People still send a lot DMCA complaints about people exploiting their images for commercial use through embedding but in embedding your are not really downloading the photo but a code provided for free by flickr that on it's own doesn't contain the image. When placing in your website, it is flickr's own services that load the photo and display it in your website. I suppose this is as part of TOS for consumers, but I have to think that the ones responsible for displaying those images on third party unauthorized sites are the people from flickr. But are they? Should you take those pics down?

Yes and no
Yes, they licence SmugMug (Flickr's owner). No, they don't licence anyone else.

You retain all intellectual property rights in and to any User Content you post, upload or otherwise make available through the Services, including the copyright in and to your photos and videos. SmugMug does not claim any ownership, right, title or interest in and to your User Content.
Notwithstanding the foregoing, by uploading and/or posting any User Content to the Services, you request, and grant SmugMug a perpetual, nonexclusive and royalty-free right to use the User Content (and the user name that is submitted in connection with such User Content) as is reasonably necessary in order to do the following: (1) provide the Services, including to display the User Content on the Services; (2) comply with your instructions pursuant to Flickr’s Data Protection Addendum; (3) comply with legal requirements, including disclosing User Content in response to legal process from governmental authorities; (4) disclose User Content without any compulsory legal process when Flickr believes there is a threat to life or limb. In the absence of a legal requirement to do so, Flickr may refrain from notifying you of Flickr’s disclosures to governmental authorities where such notification may jeopardize an important law enforcement investigation. Flickr may engage service providers for assistance with carrying out any obligation or exercising any right under these Terms of Use.


The question seems to be specifically about whether it licenses everyone else to use the embeds. So shouldn't the answer just be "no"?

is there anything specifically about embeds in the license? The whole point of them is that they get put onto third-party sites. If the user has to specifically authorize embeds, it seems like that would be an additional license.

One could think that the author is licensing this to Flickr for offering their services, but if as part of their services they offer an option to embed your images in third party sites for free, limited but free, even apparently for commercial use, then can you claim unauthorized use in those cases that abide by the service offered by flickr?
